# Display issue : put different lists in different columns of a table with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, list, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

UP

I have 2 different lists of elements in my JS that I would like to display in a table, each list in a column with ng-repeat. The problem is that my elements from the **second list appear in both columns** and I don't understand **why.**
All items display well excepted for the issue mentionned above. Here is what I've tried :

In my JS code :

**lslist, dayslist, listrbsJ1** and **listrbsJ2** are lists of elements
[here are my lists in order : lslists,listrbsJ1 and listrbsJ2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fganz.png)

```
tableau = [{
    ls: lslist
  },
  {
    days: dayslist
  },
  {
    rbsj1: listrbsJ1
  },
  {
    rbsj2: listrbsJ2
  }
];

$scope.lslist = tableau[0].ls;
$scope.dayslist = tableau[1].days;
$scope.listrbsJ1 = tableau[2].rbsj1;
$scope.listrbsJ2 = tableau[3].rbsj2;

$scope.getValue = function(ls, lsIndex, day, dayIndex) {
  return listrbsJ1[lsIndex + dayIndex * resultsJ1.length]
}

$scope.getValue2 = function(ls, lsIndex, day, dayIndex) {
  return listrbsJ2[(lsIndex - resultsJ1.length) + dayIndex * lslist.length]
}
```

In my HTML here is what I've tried:

```html
<table cellpadding="20" rules="GROUPS" frame="BOX">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Service</th>
      <th style="width: 100px" ng-repeat="day in dayslist ">{{day}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="ls in lslist track by $index" ng-init="lsIndex=$index;">
      <td style="width: 100px" class="xl153">{{ls}}</td>
      <td style="width: 100px" class="xl153" ng-repeat="days in dayslist  ">
        {{getValue(ls, $parent.$index, day , $index )}} {{getValue2(ls, $parent.$index, day , $index == $1 )}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and here is what I have in my table

In **red** are the elements from **listrbsJ1**, and in **blue** from **listrbsJ2**. So there shouldn't be anything after **listrbsJ1 in red** and the **listrbsJ2** is in the right place in the last column.
My seocnd list "listrbsJ2" **appears twice.**

[Table I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10m0T.png)

(Also it is normal for the second list in the last column to begin after the first one)

How can I correct this to ***avoid this repetition***?

I am stuck on this problem since too long, it would mean a lot if you could help me please, thanks

Also, please tell me what can I do to improve my post to be answered

Comment: Add values for `lslist`, `dayslist`, `listrbsJ1`, `listrbsJ2` for debugging

Comment: @Nitheesh I already have values for them as you can see them displayed on the picture. But the code is too long to post (the values in the lists are given in realtime from a JSON. )

Comment: @Nitheesh I've updated my post and added a picture so you can see what my lists look like

Comment: Please, can anyone help me ?